# Serializing a referenced class Object

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization, asmx

```
// Reference.cs
// Conveintly serializable
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.225")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:schemas-sc-jp:mfp:osa-1-1")]
public partial class CREDENTIALS_TYPE : CREDENTIALS_BASE_TYPE {

    private string datatypeField;

    private OPAQUE_DATA_TYPE metadataField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("data-type")]
    public string datatype {
        get {
            return this.datatypeField;
        }
        set {
            this.datatypeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public OPAQUE_DATA_TYPE metadata {
        get {
            return this.metadataField;
        }
        set {
            this.metadataField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.225")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:schemas-sc-jp:mfp:osa-1-1")]
public partial class OPAQUE_DATA_TYPE {

    private System.Xml.XmlElement[] anyField;

    private System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] anyAttrField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()]
    public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any {
        get {
            return this.anyField;
        }
        set {
            this.anyField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyAttributeAttribute()]
    public System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] AnyAttr {
        get {
            return this.anyAttrField;
        }
        set {
            this.anyAttrField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a webmethod which gets data from a device on the network, part of this data is the credentials used to authorise with the device.

We are using an API, so to recieve this data I must have the CREDENTIALS_TYPE as a parameter type in the webmethod. What I need to do is save this data, so it can be aquired without the webmethod.

Now I have serialized classes to XML files before, so I went with the familiar option, but only with classes of my own creation. **I would like to know if it's actually possible to do the same thing with a referenced class that isn't mine?**

I have to create a class that matches CREDENTIALS_TYPE and copy the data across but I haven't been able to find a way to convert between the different types.

The "CREDENTAILS_TYPE" is coming from an MFP, so reflecting and changing the code is no good in my situation because I couldn't update it anyway.

Any suggestions/advice?

Comment: Why would it matter whether the class is "yours" or not? What does "mine" even _mean_?

Comment: Mine, as in I have access to the source code and can change and recompile them.

Comment: My question is, why do you think you have to modify it?

Comment: It didn't work when I tried it.
I have *ahem* since fixed it, it does not need modification >_>

Comment: How did you fix it? If your fix would help others, you should add it as an answer, and I'll upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't modify a class you don't own the source code to, create your own DTO with the serialization attributes you require and then use [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to transfer the field data back and forth between the two.

Comment: Thank you for that, Automapper looks like it may do just what I am looking for. :)

Comment: Accepted as this is what I was looking for, I just didn't need it.